# BeautifulSoup select all href in some element with specific class

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrap images from [this](http://emblematica.grainger.illinois.edu/browse/emblems?Filter.Collection=Utrecht&Skip=0&Take=18) website. I tried with Scrapy(using Docker)and with scrapy/slenium. Scrapy seems not to work in windows10 home so I'm now trying with Selenium/Beautifulsoup. I'm using Python 3.6 with Spider into an Anaconda env.

This is how the href elements I need look like:

```
<a class="emblem" href="detail/emblem/av1615001">
```

I have to major problems:
- how should I select href with Beautifulsoup? Below in my code, you can see what I tried (but didn't work)
- As it is possible to observe the href is only a partial path to url...how should I deal with this issue?

Here my code so far:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
import urllib 
import requests
from os.path  import basename


def start_requests(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox("C:/Anaconda3/envs/scrapy/selenium/webdriver")
        #programPause = input("Press the <ENTER> key to continue...")
        self.driver.get("http://emblematica.grainger.illinois.edu/browse/emblems?Filter.Collection=Utrecht&Skip=0&Take=18")
        html = self.driver.page_source

        #html = requests.get("http://emblematica.grainger.illinois.edu/browse/emblems?Filter.Collection=Utrecht&Skip=0&Take=18")
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")        
        emblemshref = soup.select("a", {"class" : "emblem", "href" : True})

        for href in emblemshref:
            link = href["href"]
            with open(basename(link)," wb") as f:
                f.write(requests.get(link).content)

        #click on "next>>"         
        while True:
            try:
                next_page = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@id='next']")
                sleep(3)
                self.logger.info('Sleeping for 3 seconds')
                next_page.click()

                #here again the same emblemshref loop 

            except NoSuchElementException:
                #execute next on the last page
                self.logger.info('No more pages to load') 
                self.driver.quit()
                break
```

Comment: can you make your second question more clear.

Comment: Hi! Since I have to download the images when I click on the images I get the following [link](http://emblematica.grainger.illinois.edu/detail/emblem/av1615001). In the href there is only a realtive path `href="detail/emblem/av1615001"`. Is this a problem when I parse the href?

Comment: if `http://emblematica.grainger.illinois.edu/` part is not varying then you can use it as a constant like: BASE_URL = "http://emblematica.grainger.illinois.edu/" , then add this prefix to every href.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. It will give you all the urls traversing all the pages in that site. I've used `Explicit Wait` to make it faster and dynamic.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
url = "http://emblematica.grainger.illinois.edu/"
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
driver.get("http://emblematica.grainger.illinois.edu/browse/emblems?Filter.Collection=Utrecht&Skip=0&Take=18")
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".emblem")))

while True:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,"lxml")
    for item in soup.select('.emblem'):
        links = url + item['href']
        print(links)

    try:
        link = driver.find_element_by_id("next")
        link.click()
        wait.until(EC.staleness_of(link))
    except Exception:
        break
driver.quit()
```

Partial output:

```
http://emblematica.grainger.illinois.edu/detail/emblem/av1615001
http://emblematica.grainger.illinois.edu/detail/emblem/av1615002
http://emblematica.grainger.illinois.edu/detail/emblem/av1615003
```

Answer (score 2):

you can get href by class name as:

que1:

```
for link in soup.findAll('a', {'class': 'emblem'}):
   try:
      print link['href']
   except KeyError:
      pass`
```

Comment: With `soup.findAll('a', {'class': 'emblem'})`  I find all `<a>` elem.                  
`<a class="emblem" href="detail/emblem/av1615018">
<img src="http://emblemimages.grainger.illinois.edu/UtrechtVols/huygens.knaw.nl_3Aemitx_3Aav1615/JPGthumbnail/pictura/av1615018.jpg"/>
<p class="font-16">EIICE PRIMVM TRABEM</p>
</a>`.                                                                                                            When I try `print link['href']`    I get the following error: TypeError: string indices must be integers

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if above answers did the job. Here is one which does the work for me.

```
url = "SOME-URL-YOU-WANT-TO-SCRAPE"
response = requests.get(url=url)
urls = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'lxml').find_all('a', attrs={"class": ["YOUR-CLASS-NAME"]}, href=True)
```