# Selenium: Fetch href from child class element

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I need to find all `href` inside `class="mozaique"`

**My code:**

```
gfd = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('/html[1]/body[1]/div[1]/div[4]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]')
```

**html:**
[image]

Comment: Hope it will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47653309/beautifulsoup-select-all-href-in-some-element-with-specific-class

Comment: Possible duplicate of [BeautifulSoup select all href in some element with specific class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47653309/beautifulsoup-select-all-href-in-some-element-with-specific-class)

Comment: you need to use getAttribute("href") to get link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below xpath should help you fetch all the links under tag:

```
<div> class='mozaique'</div>
```

**Xpath**:

```
//div[@class='mozaique']//a[contains(@href,'')]
```

You can print the href's using the below code snippet:

```
links = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class='mozaique']//a[contains(@href,'')]')

for link in links:
    print(link.get_attribute("href"))
```

Comment: Hi thanks for reply. but It does not print the links :(

Comment: @SamSagariya, I have updated the answer. Please check and let me know if it helps

Comment: @SamSagariyan can you try with this xpath?: `//div[@class='mozaique' and child::div[contains(@id,'video_')]]//*[contains(@href,'')]`

Comment: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression!!
The links are inside a frame

Comment: So, did you try switching to the frame before actually trying to find elements? [switch to iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44834358/how-to-switch-to-an-iframe-through-selenium-and-python)

Comment: Bro ! Can you help!!
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52522884/beautifulsoup-get-whole-line-using-a-text

Answer (score 0):

First, get your parent element:

```
parent = driver.find_element_by_class_name("mozaique")
```

Then get a list of all 'a' tags within your parent element.

```
a = parent.find_elements_by_tag_name("a")
```

Then run a loop to print the hrefs

```
for x in a:
    print(x.get_attribute("href"))
```

Comment: print(x.get_attribute("href"))  This would give  Element does not exist error.