# Extracting variables from Javascript inside HTML

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I need all the lines which contains the text '.mp4'. The Html file has no tag!

My code:

```
import urllib.request
import demjson
url = ('https://myurl')
content = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
       /* <![CDATA[ */
               function getEmbed(width, height) {
         if (width && height) {
          return '<iframe width="' + width + '" height="' + height + '" src="https://www.ptrex.com/embed/33247" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen oallowfullscreen msallowfullscreen></iframe>';
         }
         return '<iframe width="768" height="432" src="https://www.ptrex.com/embed/33247" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen oallowfullscreen msallowfullscreen></iframe>';
        }
       
       var flashvars = {
                 video_id: '33247',                  license_code: '$535555517668914',                  rnd: '1537972655',                  video_url: 'https://www.ptrex.com/get_file/4/996a9088fdf801992d24457cd51469f3f7aaaee6a0/33000/33247/33247.mp4/',                  postfix: '.mp4',                  video_url_text: '480p',                  video_alt_url: 'https://www.ptrex.com/get_file/4/774833c428771edee2cf401ef2264e746a06f9f370/33000/33247/33247_720p.mp4/',                  video_alt_url_text: '720p HD',                  video_alt_url_hd: '1',                  timeline_screens_url: '//di-iu49il1z.leasewebultracdn.com/contents/videos_screenshots/33000/33247/timelines/timeline_mp4/200x116/{time}.jpg',                  timeline_screens_interval: '10',                  preview_url: '//di-iu49il1z.leasewebultracdn.com/contents/videos_screenshots/33000/33247/preview.mp4.jpg',                  skin: 'youtube.css',                  bt: '1',                  volume: '1',                  hide_controlbar: '1',                  hide_style: 'fade',                  related_src: 'https://www.ptrex.com/related_videos_html/33247/',                  adv_pre_vast: 'https://pt.ptawe.com/vast/v3?psid=ed_pntrexvb1&utm_source=bf1&utm_medium=network&ms_notrack=1',                  lrcv: '1556867449254522707330811',                  adv_pre_replay_after: '2',                  embed: '1'               };
              var player_obj = kt_player('kt_player', 'https://www.ptrex.com/player/kt_player.swf?v=4.0.2', '100%', '100%', flashvars);
       /* ]]> */
      </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use BeautifulSoup to extract the `<script>` tag, but you would still need an alternative approach to extract the information inside.

Some Python can be used to first extract `flashvars` and then pass this to `demjson` to convert the Javascript dictionary into a Python one. For example:

```
import demjson

content = """<script type="text/javascript">/* <![CDATA[ */ 
... 
...
</script>"""

script_var = content.split('var flashvars = ')[1]
script_var = script_var[:script_var.find('};') + 1]
data = demjson.decode(script_var)

print(data['video_url'])
print(data['video_alt_url'])
```

This would then display:

```
https://www.ptrex.com/get_file/4/996a9088fdf801992d24457cd51469f3f7aaaee6a0/33000/33247/33247.mp4/
https://www.ptrex.com/get_file/4/774833c428771edee2cf401ef2264e746a06f9f370/33000/33247/33247_720p.mp4/
```

`demjson` is an alternative JSON decoder which can be installed via PIP

```
pip install demjson
```

Comment: Thanks for helping! :)
But i get this error :TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Comment: How to read my url. i have edited my code. hope it will be helpful.

Comment: What is `content`? Is it from a `requests.get()` ?

Comment: Depending on the URL you use you will need to use `.decode('utf-8')` to convert it into a string. e.g. `content = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read().decode('utf-8')`